# Limit django path slug to a list

Tags: django

I currently have a path like such

```
    path('<slug:slug>/', ToSlugPage.as_view()),
```

Is there any way to limit the results slug can be for this path, and if so how?

So for example, if I have a list of slugs

```
slugs = ['page1', 'page2', 'page3']
```

Is there any way I can have slug check that, if not continue to other paths/return 404?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Path converters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#registering-custom-path-converters) for customize url parameters. In that doc says:

> A to_python(self, value) method, which handles converting the matched string into the type that should be passed to the view function. It should raise ValueError if it can’t convert the given value. A ValueError is interpreted as no match and as a consequence a 404 response is sent to the user unless another URL pattern matches.

for example:
in converts.py

```
class CustomUrlParameterType:
    valid_pages = ['page1', 'page2', 'page3']

    
    def to_python(self, value):
        if value not in self.valid_pages:
            raise ValueError
        return value

    def to_url(self, value):
        return value
```

in urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, register_converter

from . import converters, views

register_converter(converters.CustomUrlParameterType, 'custom_type')

urlpatterns = [
    ...
       path('<custom_type:slug>/', ToSlugPage.as_view()),
    ...
]
```

Also, you can retrieve your parameters from url as query params.

Comment: I tried this, but it gives the error that `AttributeError: 'CustomUrlParameterType' object has no attribute 'regex'`

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/urls/#registering-custom-path-converters

> For more complex matching requirements, you can define your own path converters.
>
> A converter is a class that includes the following:
>
> - A **regex** class attribute, as a string.
> - A **to_python(self, value)** method, which handles converting the matched string into the type that should be passed to the view function. It should raise **ValueError** if it can’t convert the given value. A **ValueError** is interpreted as no match and as a consequence a 404 response is sent to the user unless another URL pattern matches.
> - A **to_url(self, value)** method, which handles converting the Python type into a string to be used in the URL. It should raise **ValueError** if it can’t convert the given value. A **ValueError** is interpreted as no match and as a consequence **reverse()** will raise **NoReverseMatch** unless another URL pattern matches.

```py
class CustomUrlParameterType:
    regex = "|".join(['page1', 'page2', 'page3'])
    
    def to_python(self, value):
        if re.match(CustomUrlParameterType.regex, value):
            return value
        raise ValueError(f"{value} doesn't match {CustomUrlParameterType.regex}")

    def to_url(self, value):
        return self.to_python(value)
```

A `regex` class variable is required. Raising `ValueError` is recommended.